# Unable to use Firebase /Firestore functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my js file I can't use get(), firebase ... it returns me an Any. I have imported correctly the files on the index.html.

To be clearer on my question, is it normal that the firestore function is in Any.? If not what is the way to remedy this? I specify that the sending via a data form works perfectly. Of course I have modified the Rules to avoid being blocked.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqTQJ.png)

Comment: what is the value of snapshot inside then() callback?

Comment: For us to help you please edit your question, create a reproducible codes, expected output and include the error. These links can help [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)